# String or binary data would be truncated. on SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I've got a problem with a select statement. It works in SQL Server but it yels the error in title when used in C#

SO My SQL Statement looks like this

```
  declare @312341v1Whenaddakeylength128charatsendingreportonP varchar(max)= 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec faucibus nulla ut lorem ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam laoreet. Proin convallis est ut euismod rhoncus. Donec in magna eleifend, dictum neque non, pellentesque diam. Aliquam faucibus fringilla ex, vitae posuere lectus rhoncus congue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam mollis vel enim at consequat. Integer porta feugiat sem, a condimentum felis hendrerit ac. Quisque lobortis placerat sodales. Nam et nunc nulla.

Pellentesque vel risus vel sem pellentesque feugiat. Ut sodales odio sollicitudin, consequat nisi quis, lobortis ex. Donec fermentum ante massa, luctus auctor sapien consectetur ac. Phasellus auctor nunc lorem, ultricies sollicitudin metus placerat ut. Proin non viverra erat. Maecenas malesuada orci mi. Curabitur vel dolor a ex ultrices posuere. Sed id quam porta lorem venenatis auctor sed a dolor. Suspendisse lobortis mauris blandit lacinia semper. Nunc nisl orci, porta nec maximus id, imperdiet vitae purus. Aenean a elit id augue suscipit pretium vel nec risus. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque facilisis mauris eu orci sagittis semper. Suspendisse at placerat mauris.

Sed vulputate est quis justo mattis convallis. Aenean tempor auctor arcu eget suscipit. Maecenas ac vehicula neque, ut placerat lorem. Integer felis lectus, varius sit amet neque auctor, ultrices interdum mauris. Ut fringilla, sapien id auctor blandit, enim diam tempus neque, eu tempus libero nibh a purus. Maecenas bibendum ligula ut malesuada placerat. Morbi egestas commodo velit eu egestas. Phasellus sed iaculis justo. Sed ipsum nisl, molestie ac luctus sit amet, fringilla luctus felis. Nullam vitae lorem in metus blandit maximus.

Nunc hendrerit odio quis felis mattis bibendum sed ut neque. Praesent blandit nunc in elit semper feugiat a a mi. Pellentesque a cursus nisi. Etiam maximus tristique elementum. Praesent finibus blandit sagittis. Morbi mollis leo justo, ut malesuada mauris ullamcorper sit amet. Ut eu bibendum justo. Integer tempus elit erat, non egestas urna tristique in. Quisque et massa nec felis rutrum posuere ut vitae sapien. Ut semper euismod mauris ac blandit. Vivamus dignissim est sit amet maximus volutpat. Cras fermentum massa nunc, non tincidunt erat rutrum vitae.

Ut commodo ullamcorper erat, eget sollicitudin nisl lacinia sed. Phasellus fermentum felis ac urna elementum, et bibendum nunc sagittis. Curabitur vestibulum tristique ante ut consequat. Pellentesque egestas ex sit amet mauris ultrices, malesuada bibendum est finibus. Curabitur ac feugiat arcu. Nam auctor pulvinar molestie. Quisque feugiat, nulla non rhoncus blandit, orci leo interdum eros, in imperdiet libero ante nec mauris. Morbi id aliquam purus, quis posuere magna. Nunc vel sem eget ante rhoncus imperdiet eu et leo.

Quisque ac malesuada est. Maecenas a dolor vitae turpis ultricies vestibulum. Quisque tincidunt lorem volutpat, eleifend nulla vel, dictum lorem. Nullam id imperdiet nunc, posuere hendrerit nulla. In volutpat, augue ut posuere ultricies, lectus sapien condimentum lectus, in consequat nibh nisi quis dolor. Cras rhoncus mi pellentesque massa dignissim convallis. Vivamus eu eleifend felis, vel eleifend dui. Etiam vitae sapien nunc. Integer est quam, sodales quis dolor vel, commodo sodales urna. Sed ac sapien ligula. Cras tempor felis vitae justo ullamcorper, ut venenatis risus commodo. Fusce lobortis egestas commodo.

Sed at libero quis mauris ultricies aliquam vel feugiat lorem. Donec pharetra vitae libero id placerat. Aliquam suscipit porta urna, a hendrerit mauris ullamcorper sit amet. Phasellus mollis diam sagittis metus dapibus, ac porta tortor euismod. Nam quam lacus, dignissim quis feugiat ut, rhoncus sit amet augue. Vestibulum molestie egestas venenatis. Ut a nulla in augue pretium tincidunt quis eget ex. Phasellus blandit bibendum neque. Sed laoreet ullamcorper justo. Morbi non sodales justo. Integer dignissim varius tincidunt. Nulla sagittis, sem ut tempor porta, lorem leo elementum sapien, sed sollicitudin diam nisl sed massa. Etiam egestas mauris nec bibendum pulvinar. Etiam sed nisl cursus, luctus augue non, pharetra enim. Suspendisse ac magna nisl. Mauris tempus eu mauris malesuada consectetur.

Duis tincidunt vitae diam et mattis. Donec laoreet euismod aliquam. Donec at efficitur sapien, vel lacinia ante. Proin vehicula ut quam vitae faucibus. Nam venenatis est sit amet tortor varius, quis sollicitudin lectus placerat. Donec vel aliquet tellus. Integer pellentesque leo sit amet lorem luctus, eu tempor nisl tincidunt.

Suspendisse turpis felis, euismod at auctor vel, hendrerit auctor sapien. Mauris finibus interdum vestibulum. Donec quis dolor ac orci commodo efficitur. Nullam in porttitor ipsum, a commodo mauris. Proin et blandit erat. Mauris posuere lacus non leo pulvinar, dignissim aliquam augue vulputate. Nullam et consequat augue, ac ultricies nibh.

Morbi vestibulum, orci eu molestie convallis, ligula felis convallis lectus, in congue tellus augue et purus. Nulla non dui urna. Aliquam at mattis mauris. Phasellus eget congue urna. Phasellus sollicitudin tellus leo, vel efficitur magna condimentum nec. Donec venenatis feugiat blandit. Quisque erat elit, feugiat nec orci volutpat, semper maximus turpis. Nulla rutrum molestie dolor sed varius. Morbi scelerisque quam dui, ac blandit leo rutrum nec. Vivamus vel maximus orci, at malesuada purus. Cras gravida vulputate augue, sit amet dictum erat aliquet cursus. Ut purus nibh, aliquam vel tincidunt a, vehicula sit amet nulla. Suspendisse ultrices, tortor eget tristique rhoncus, mi elit feugiat ante, ut elementum lacus quam a dolor. Vestibulum nibh justo, dapibus vitae massa vel, pellentesque iaculis tellus.

Fusce eu volutpat leo. Nunc luctus quis lorem nec mattis. Pellentesque eget sagittis sem. Curabitur mattis ligula ut iaculis accumsan. Aliquam ut enim ac magna hendrerit porttitor. In nec lorem non neque euismod luctus. Praesent euismod purus nec leo egestas lobortis.

Nunc eros ipsum, tincidunt a purus at, maximus lobortis ipsum. Sed condimentum, turpis non commodo ornare, ligula purus gravida sapien, in interdum elit risus sit amet nibh. Curabitur mattis cursus ligula. In ut lectus et massa iaculis dignissim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac sed.'


  SELECT * , CASE  WHEN Column1 LIKE '%' + @312341v1Whenaddakeylength128charatsendingreportonP+ '%' 
  THEN 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec faucibus nulla ut lorem ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam laoreet. Proin convallis est ut euismod rhoncus. Donec in magna eleifend, dictum neque non, pellentesque diam. Aliquam faucibus fringilla ex, vitae posuere lectus rhoncus congue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam mollis vel enim at consequat. Integer porta feugiat sem, a condimentum felis hendrerit ac. Quisque lobortis placerat sodales. Nam et nunc nulla.

Pellentesque vel risus vel sem pellentesque feugiat. Ut sodales odio sollicitudin, consequat nisi quis, lobortis ex. Donec fermentum ante massa, luctus auctor sapien consectetur ac. Phasellus auctor nunc lorem, ultricies sollicitudin metus placerat ut. Proin non viverra erat. Maecenas malesuada orci mi. Curabitur vel dolor a ex ultrices posuere. Sed id quam porta lorem venenatis auctor sed a dolor. Suspendisse lobortis mauris blandit lacinia semper. Nunc nisl orci, porta nec maximus id, imperdiet vitae purus. Aenean a elit id augue suscipit pretium vel nec risus. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque facilisis mauris eu orci sagittis semper. Suspendisse at placerat mauris.

Sed vulputate est quis justo mattis convallis. Aenean tempor auctor arcu eget suscipit. Maecenas ac vehicula neque, ut placerat lorem. Integer felis lectus, varius sit amet neque auctor, ultrices interdum mauris. Ut fringilla, sapien id auctor blandit, enim diam tempus neque, eu tempus libero nibh a purus. Maecenas bibendum ligula ut malesuada placerat. Morbi egestas commodo velit eu egestas. Phasellus sed iaculis justo. Sed ipsum nisl, molestie ac luctus sit amet, fringilla luctus felis. Nullam vitae lorem in metus blandit maximus.

Nunc hendrerit odio quis felis mattis bibendum sed ut neque. Praesent blandit nunc in elit semper feugiat a a mi. Pellentesque a cursus nisi. Etiam maximus tristique elementum. Praesent finibus blandit sagittis. Morbi mollis leo justo, ut malesuada mauris ullamcorper sit amet. Ut eu bibendum justo. Integer tempus elit erat, non egestas urna tristique in. Quisque et massa nec felis rutrum posuere ut vitae sapien. Ut semper euismod mauris ac blandit. Vivamus dignissim est sit amet maximus volutpat. Cras fermentum massa nunc, non tincidunt erat rutrum vitae.

Ut commodo ullamcorper erat, eget sollicitudin nisl lacinia sed. Phasellus fermentum felis ac urna elementum, et bibendum nunc sagittis. Curabitur vestibulum tristique ante ut consequat. Pellentesque egestas ex sit amet mauris ultrices, malesuada bibendum est finibus. Curabitur ac feugiat arcu. Nam auctor pulvinar molestie. Quisque feugiat, nulla non rhoncus blandit, orci leo interdum eros, in imperdiet libero ante nec mauris. Morbi id aliquam purus, quis posuere magna. Nunc vel sem eget ante rhoncus imperdiet eu et leo.

Quisque ac malesuada est. Maecenas a dolor vitae turpis ultricies vestibulum. Quisque tincidunt lorem volutpat, eleifend nulla vel, dictum lorem. Nullam id imperdiet nunc, posuere hendrerit nulla. In volutpat, augue ut posuere ultricies, lectus sapien condimentum lectus, in consequat nibh nisi quis dolor. Cras rhoncus mi pellentesque massa dignissim convallis. Vivamus eu eleifend felis, vel eleifend dui. Etiam vitae sapien nunc. Integer est quam, sodales quis dolor vel, commodo sodales urna. Sed ac sapien ligula. Cras tempor felis vitae justo ullamcorper, ut venenatis risus commodo. Fusce lobortis egestas commodo.

Sed at libero quis mauris ultricies aliquam vel feugiat lorem. Donec pharetra vitae libero id placerat. Aliquam suscipit porta urna, a hendrerit mauris ullamcorper sit amet. Phasellus mollis diam sagittis metus dapibus, ac porta tortor euismod. Nam quam lacus, dignissim quis feugiat ut, rhoncus sit amet augue. Vestibulum molestie egestas venenatis. Ut a nulla in augue pretium tincidunt quis eget ex. Phasellus blandit bibendum neque. Sed laoreet ullamcorper justo. Morbi non sodales justo. Integer dignissim varius tincidunt. Nulla sagittis, sem ut tempor porta, lorem leo elementum sapien, sed sollicitudin diam nisl sed massa. Etiam egestas mauris nec bibendum pulvinar. Etiam sed nisl cursus, luctus augue non, pharetra enim. Suspendisse ac magna nisl. Mauris tempus eu mauris malesuada consectetur.

Duis tincidunt vitae diam et mattis. Donec laoreet euismod aliquam. Donec at efficitur sapien, vel lacinia ante. Proin vehicula ut quam vitae faucibus. Nam venenatis est sit amet tortor varius, quis sollicitudin lectus placerat. Donec vel aliquet tellus. Integer pellentesque leo sit amet lorem luctus, eu tempor nisl tincidunt.

Suspendisse turpis felis, euismod at auctor vel, hendrerit auctor sapien. Mauris finibus interdum vestibulum. Donec quis dolor ac orci commodo efficitur. Nullam in porttitor ipsum, a commodo mauris. Proin et blandit erat. Mauris posuere lacus non leo pulvinar, dignissim aliquam augue vulputate. Nullam et consequat augue, ac ultricies nibh.

Morbi vestibulum, orci eu molestie convallis, ligula felis convallis lectus, in congue tellus augue et purus. Nulla non dui urna. Aliquam at mattis mauris. Phasellus eget congue urna. Phasellus sollicitudin tellus leo, vel efficitur magna condimentum nec. Donec venenatis feugiat blandit. Quisque erat elit, feugiat nec orci volutpat, semper maximus turpis. Nulla rutrum molestie dolor sed varius. Morbi scelerisque quam dui, ac blandit leo rutrum nec. Vivamus vel maximus orci, at malesuada purus. Cras gravida vulputate augue, sit amet dictum erat aliquet cursus. Ut purus nibh, aliquam vel tincidunt a, vehicula sit amet nulla. Suspendisse ultrices, tortor eget tristique rhoncus, mi elit feugiat ante, ut elementum lacus quam a dolor. Vestibulum nibh justo, dapibus vitae massa vel, pellentesque iaculis tellus.

Fusce eu volutpat leo. Nunc luctus quis lorem nec mattis. Pellentesque eget sagittis sem. Curabitur mattis ligula ut iaculis accumsan. Aliquam ut enim ac magna hendrerit porttitor. In nec lorem non neque euismod luctus. Praesent euismod purus nec leo egestas lobortis.

Nunc eros ipsum, tincidunt a purus at, maximus lobortis ipsum. Sed condimentum, turpis non commodo ornare, ligula purus gravida sapien, in interdum elit risus sit amet nibh. Curabitur mattis cursus ligula. In ut lectus et massa iaculis dignissim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac sed.' 
  END as ErrorCode FROM Table rpmsp WHERE   Column1 LIKE '%' + @312341v1Whenaddakeylength128charatsendingreportonP+ '%'
```

So this statement works fine in SQL it return 0 rows but doesn't throw exception.

In c#

```
 SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            try{ dataReader.Read(); }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                var x = 1;
            }
```

This throws an exception on line dataReader.Read(); the exception is `String or binary data would be truncated`. I have no idea why, because i do no inserts it's just a dynamic select.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it because of the long string returned?  Could you cast the long string in the SELECT to nvarchar(max) explicitly?  Does the problem go away if you shorten down the returned string dramatically?  (as an experiment)

Comment: Is there any other code? Specifically, does `sqlCommand` take parameters? Specifically, would `@312341v1Whenaddakeylength128charatsendingreportonP` be a parameter? And if so, as what length is it declared?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton yes it is it works for 3000 chars it throws exception at over 3500 from what i've tested.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes it does take params `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharsFromString(keyValue), keyValue);`

Comment: @CiucaS: [Don't use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). .NET will guess the parameter type. In this case it should guess `[N]VARCHAR(<length of your string>)`, but it will probably not guess `MAX`. If your parameter is `VARCHAR(MAX)`, use `.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = keyValue`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ty for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: @CiucaS: it wasn't a suggestion, it was an attempt at solving your problem. :-P I take it it didn't?

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes i think this would work, as I said i limited the number of chars to 3000 for now, as this long string was only for purpose tests. I will get back to it when i have the time.

Answer (score 1):

We built a process that export some of our tables to an external DB Server.
We use views that return data in XML format.

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table for xml auto
```

I detect that in c#, (we use an stored procedure and .ExecuteNonQuery()), it returns more than one row for every single xml file, I think that it uses 2K packets.

Then, reading sequentially all rows and using an StringBuilder, rebuild the text again.

```
StringBuilder xml_text = new StringBuilder();
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    xml_text.Append(row[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: mcNets ty, this could be a good solution in case  you need longs string. For me it was a test case that failed and wasn't sure what causes that fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a C# issue. It is a SQL as you can tell by the error message. The root issue is the SQL Server is not consistently casting the datatype/size of the string.

Add explicit casting in your SQL for all strings to varchar(max)

Comment: I thought so too, but the query works in SQL. Anyways i've limited the number of chars to less then 3000 an it's ok. I was just curios why i get this error for a valid SQL Query, but i guess it's something related to how C# process SQL Queries.

Comment: @CiucaS nope, that is an error out of SQL Server. 100%. Queries aren't guaranteed to generate identical execution plans nor behave exactly the same if not explicitly instructed to.